# Using pyTDMS in Python

Tags: python, labview

I am currently running a labview script that uses a DAQmx controller to take in voltage readings from batteries. The script takes in the voltage data and the amount of time that the test was run for and writes a TDMS file.

I would like to write a python script to take in this TDMS file and average some of the values. I have not been able to figure out how to use pyTDMS in order to read in this file.

Does anyone know how to use pyTDMS in python?

this is what my file looks like when I open it in notepad++

TDSm®   i  ä      ä            /ÿÿÿÿ      name       junk071316_164717   /'DAQ Assistant_0'ÿÿÿÿ       /'DAQ Assistant_0'/'Voltage'i  ÿÿÿÿ                                             NI_Scaling_Status       unscaled   NI_Number_Of_Scales         NI_Scale[1]_Scale_Type       Linear   NI_Scale[1]_Linear_Slope
   I H Hà4?   NI_Scale[1]_Linear_Y_Intercept
       ¿Ú$À   NI_Scale[1]_Linear_Input_Source          /'DAQ Assistant_0'/'Voltage_0'i  ÿÿÿÿ                                            NI_Scaling_Status       unscaled   NI_Number_Of_Scales         NI_Scale[1]_Scale_Type       Linear   NI_Scale[1]_Linear_Slope
   ò`ò`òà4?   NI_Scale[1]_Linear_Y_Intercept
      `IÝ$À   N

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally we ask that users submit questions as [mcve] so that others can better answer them.

Comment: Do you have a sample TDMS file?

Comment: Yes I will attached one

Comment: The pyTDMS page at https://github.com/petebachant/pyTDMS gives the usage as `objects, rawdata = pytdms.read(filename)`. What do you get when you do this? What do `print(objects)` and `print(rawdata)` return?

Comment: When I run the pytdms module I get this error:

  File "C:\Users\mmunoz\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytdms.py", line 173, in getValue
    return struct.unpack(code, s)[0]

IndexError: tuple index out of range